# Parsing xml response from ebay getsellerlist with php

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to parse XML with PHP. The XML is a response from ebay getsellerlist api, and is structured like so:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<getsellerlistresponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <timestamp>2016-08-11T14:17:39.869Z</timestamp>
    <ack>Success</ack>
    <version>967</version>
    <build>E967_CORE_APISELLING_17965876_R1</build>
        <itemarray>
            <item>
                <itemid>itemid1</itemid>
                <listingdetails>
                    <viewitemurl>itemurl1</viewitemurl>
                </listingdetails>
                <primarycategory>
                <categoryid>categoryid1</categoryid>
                <categoryname>categoryname1</categoryname>
            </primarycategory>
            <title>title1</title>
            <picturedetails>
                <galleryurl>url1</galleryurl>
                <photodisplay>thumbnail1</pictureurl>
                <pictureurl>picture1</pictureurl>
            </picturedetails>
        </item>
    </itemarray>
</getsellerlistresponse>
```

My php is as follows:

```
<?
    $xml = '<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?--><getsellerlistresponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents"><timestamp>2016-08-11T14:17:39.869Z</timestamp><ack>Success</ack><version>967</version><build>E967_CORE_APISELLING_17965876_R1</build><itemarray><item><itemid>itemid1</itemid><listingdetails><viewitemurl>itemurl1</viewitemurl></listingdetails><primarycategory><categoryid>categoryid1</categoryid><categoryname>categoryname1</categoryname></primarycategory><title>title1</title><picturedetails><galleryurl>url1</galleryurl><photodisplay>thumbnail1</pictureurl><pictureurl>picture1</pictureurl></picturedetails></item><item><itemid>itemid2</itemid><listingdetails><viewitemurl>itemurl2</viewitemurl></listingdetails><primarycategory><categoryid>categoryid2</categoryid><categoryname>categoryname2</categoryname></primarycategory><title>title1</title><picturedetails><galleryurl>url2</galleryurl><photodisplay>thumbnail2</pictureurl><pictureurl>picture2</pictureurl></picturedetails></item></itemarray></getsellerlistresponse>';
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadXML($xml);
    $title_nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title');

    $titles = array();

    foreach ($title_nodes as $node) {
        $titles[] = $node->nodeValue;
        echo $node->nodeValue;
    }
    echo $titles[0];
    echo count($titles);
?>
```

When I run it, I get a blank page, no errors, nothing.
If I check $titles length using count(), it comes back as zero.
For some reason it is not getting the title node (or any other nodes) and I can't figure out how to parse the xml string with php and get the node values.

Any help most appreciated, if the question is vague or lacking detail, please let me know and I will correct it.

Comment: Turn on error reporting. There are definitely errors

Comment: its already in plain sight up there in your xml `<photodisplay>thumbnail1</pictureurl>`

Comment: Thank you for the responses, I do have error reporting on as it does generate the expected error if a semi-colon is omitted at the end of a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML isn't valid:

> Unable to parse any XML input. org.jdom2.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 2: The element type "photodisplay" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".

And that's only *after* you remove the comments in your XML declaration:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
```

shoud be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

[Working demo](https://eval.in/621415):

```
<?php

$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<getsellerlistresponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <timestamp>2016-08-11T14:17:39.869Z</timestamp>
    <ack>Success</ack>
    <version>967</version>
    <build>E967_CORE_APISELLING_17965876_R1</build>
        <itemarray>
            <item>
                <itemid>itemid1</itemid>
                <listingdetails>
                    <viewitemurl>itemurl1</viewitemurl>
                </listingdetails>
                <primarycategory>
                <categoryid>categoryid1</categoryid>
                <categoryname>categoryname1</categoryname>
            </primarycategory>
            <title>title1</title>
            <picturedetails>
                <galleryurl>url1</galleryurl>
                <photodisplay>thumbnail1</photodisplay>
                <pictureurl>picture1</pictureurl>
            </picturedetails>
        </item>
    </itemarray>
</getsellerlistresponse>';
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadXML($xml);
    $title_nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title');

    $titles = array();

    foreach ($title_nodes as $node) {
        $titles[] = $node->nodeValue;
        echo $node->nodeValue;
    }
    echo $titles[0];
    echo count($titles);
```

Comment: Looking into this, thank you, will check back in a bit

Comment: I've corrected the XML in the script, and it still gives me a blank page.